# Почему я не могу спарсить время?

Tags: java, datetime

Я пытаюсь спарсить текущее время по моему паттерну, используя DateTimeFormatter, но получаю ошибку. Я уверен, что использую правильный паттерн времени. Почему это происходит и как можно пофиксить?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        String time = now.toString();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
        LocalDateTime result = LocalDateTime.parse(time, formatter);
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2023-12-05T14:26:53.767' could not be parsed at index 2
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Заголовок тоже переведите, и уберите английский текст. "Я уверен, что использую правильный паттерн времени" - но ведь он неправильный. Посмотрите, как у вас выглядят паттерн и строка даты. Они не совпадают.

Comment: 1 - для такого формата есть готовый форматтер DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME 2 - зачем LocalDateTime преобразовывать в строку и тут же пытаться обратно распарсить в LocalDateTime?

Comment: insolor, Я хочу получить текущее время в формате "01.01.2023 12:00",  DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME возвращает время в формате 2023-12-05T14:42:23.921 
А это не то, что мне нужно. Все преобразования в коде для наглядности

Comment: Вам нужно не распарсить текущее время, а наоборот отформатировать объект времени вашим форматтером: `System.out.println(formatter.format(LocalDateTime.now()))` (или `System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter))`). `now.toString()` вообще не  нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что Вы сначала преобразовываете время
`LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now()` в строку через `now.toString()`, а затем снова парсите его обратно в `LocalDateTime`. Это вызывает ошибку, потому что `now.toString()` возвращает строку в формате ISO, который не соответствует шаблону `"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"`.

Вот **правильный код:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
        String formattedTime = now.format(formatter);
        System.out.println(formattedTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло и теперь стало понятно